# Asynchronous calls start a decline and stop running in parallel over time

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asmx

While converting a traditional .net web forms application to angular, small parts are being converted as custom components and the .js files are hosted in aspx pages. Since the api is not public, the angular ajax calls are proxied through WebMethods in an .asmx page for authenticated users.

The WebService's web methods are all async in the form of:

```
Private Async Function CallPutEndpointAsync(urlString As String, putBodyObj As Object) As Task(Of String)
    Utilities.EnableGZip()
    Dim response = Await GetHttpResponseMessageForPut(urlString, putBodyObj)
    Dim responseString = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

    Return responseString
End Function

Private Async Function GetHttpResponseMessageForPut(urlString As String, putBodyObj As Object) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
    Dim client = GetHttpClient()
    Dim content = New StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(putBodyObj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

    Return Await client.PutAsync(urlString, content)
End Function

Private Function GetHttpClient() As HttpClient
    Dim client As New HttpClient
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ClientKey", GetClientKey())
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UserId", GetUserId())

    Return client
End Function
```

Those functions get called many times when the angular app loads to get dashboard'esque data.
The puzzling part is the first few calls seem to fire asynchronously and then all the sudden there is a decline or some sort of serialized access to a resource. The asmx calls a .NET Core Web Api for data. I am trying to figure out if there is some sort of serialization to a resource in the client(angular/asmx) or in the api calls. Does this look familiar to anyone?

[image]

Comment: What does the `GetHttpClient` method look like? If you're not already, you might want to consider using [the `IHttpClientFactory` service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests) to resolve the `HttpClient` instances.

Comment: I added the missing function where the HttpClient is created.

Comment: Well, that's definitely the wrong way to do it. :) Either create a singleton instance of the `HttpClient` class for your entire application, or use the `IHttpClientFactory` service to return an `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: @RichardDeeming - The code using the HttpClient is ASP.NET code. The IHttpClientFactory is only in .net core :(

Comment: You can use `IHttpClientFactory` in .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later by referencing [the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/).